# Nodejs Serving 2 Angular Apps Share Single Route

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes, server

I have a nodeJS server hosting two static angular apps. One of the apps, lets say app1, is default with a `baseHref:'/'` and another app, app2 with a `baseHref:'/square/'`.
Although they are separate apps when using app2, I want to share one route, `/login` to lead to the index.html of app1.

my server.js hosts the 2 static routes as:

```
app.get('/app2', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/DineNGo-Square/index.html'));
});
app.get('/app2/*', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/DineNGo-Square/index.html'));
});

app.get('*', function(req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/DineNGo/index2.html'));
});
```

I want it so that routing to `app2/login` uses the `index2.html` and all other routes with app2 route to go to `index.html`.

How can I do that. If I add a dedicated route, the other static routes fail for app2. I want the app2/login endpoint to point to serverURL/login or index2.html.

I rather handle this from the server rather than changing the fronend of app2 because of the prefix associated to the app2 baseHref.